# formatting columns group Pdf tabulator

Tags: tabulator

when I try to download a table with grouping by fields, it does not appear correctly in the pdf, can anyone help me?
ç[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the `null` values appearing in the output. If so then you can use an [accessor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/mutators#accessors) on the column definitions to convert the null value into an empty string so it renders correctly.

To start with we define an accessor function outside of Tabulator:

```js
var nullFixingAccessor = function(value){
    return value === null ? "" : value; //return value or empty string if it is null
}
```

Then in each column definition for a column that might contain a null we set it on the ***accessorDownload*** property:

```js
{title:"Act", field:"act", accessorDownload:nullFixingAccessor},
```

This will then convert the null values to an empty string when the pdf is downloaded